# Smartphone GPS enabled and Camera GPS enabled, but still can not see exif data of longitude and latitude

Tags: android, html, gps, exif, samsung-mobile

I have this html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>exif test</title>
    <style>

    </style>
    <script src="http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/exif/exif.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/binaryajax/binaryajax.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <img src="pic.jpg" exif="true" id="foo"/>

  </body>
  <script>
        var oImg = document.getElementById("foo");
   </script>
</html>
```

and my camera location services is turned ON.

however, on the console when I load this page and enter:

```
EXIF.getAllTags(oImg)
```

I get all the information except the GPS tags, even though I enabled them on my phone (Samsung S4). My question is, is there any reason an exif would not include location information even though the appropriate settings are enabled?